# Respaldo Automatico Firestore

Tags: base-de-datos, firebase, google-api, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-platform

Me encuentro creando una funcion para hacer backups automaticos a mi base de datos, sigo al pie de la letra la guia para realizar la exportacion de datos sin embargo cuando pruebo la funcion cloud plataform me arroja error. Este es el codigo que saqué de la guia para el index.js.cion de datos de firestore sin embargo a pesar de seguir la [guia](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export) la funcion arroja error de codigo. a continuacion dejo los codigos que estoy utilizando para el package.json y el index.js.

```html
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();
// Replace BUCKET_NAME
const bucket = 'gs://databasesso'

exports.scheduledFirestoreExport = (event, context) => {
  const databaseName = client.databasePath(
    process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    '(default)'
  );

  return client
    .exportDocuments({
      name: databaseName,
      outputUriPrefix: bucket,
      // Leave collectionIds empty to export all collections
      // or define a list of collection IDs:
      // collectionIds: ['users', 'posts']
      collectionIds: [Chequeo_Oficinas],
    })
    .then(responses => {
      const response = responses[0];
      console.log(`Operation Name: ${response['name']}`);
      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

```html
{
  "name": "sample-pubsub",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^0.18.0",

    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^1.3.0"
  }
  
}
```

Comment: que error ? ...

Comment: al momento de probar la funcion arroja esto

$
Error: function execution failed. Details:
Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined